# Need to set variables(attributes) for HttpServletResponse

Tags: servlets, parameters, attributes

I have a working code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/getData.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getData(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model
        ,@RequestBody Map reqbody)
  throws Exception{

    List result = testService.selectData(reqbody);
    model.addAttribute("grid", result); 

    return "jsonview";
}
```

Now, I want to change above code to below style.
- adding data to response instead of model.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/getData.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
        ,@RequestBody Map reqbody)
  throws Exception{

    List result = testService.selectData(reqbody);
    //model.addAttribute("grid", result);   
    //add result to response here...

    return "jsonview";
}
```

Any suggestion??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with session you can do the next step.

> request.getSession().setAtribute("nameVarible","valor")

PD: Excuse me gramatic but I am trying to learn English

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your intention is, but you can not set attribute to [response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) object. You can only set attribute in request object. Since you already have a request parameter, change your code as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test/getData.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String getData(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Map reqbody)throws Exception{

   List result = testService.selectData(reqbody);
   request.setAttribute("grid", result);   
   return "jsonview";
}
```